# Error when attempting to download redis-stack using homebrew on Apple M1 Silicon Macbook

Tags: redis, node-redis, redis-stack

First I ran `brew tap redis-stack/redis-stack`
Then I ran `brew install redis-stack`. I ended up getting this error:

==> Downloading https://redismodules.s3.amazonaws.com/redis-stack/.donotremove
curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Error: Download failed on Cask 'redis-stack' with message: Download failed: https://redismodules.s3.amazonaws.com/redis-stack/.donotremove

I already have redis installed using homebrew. If anyone can help me with this, thanks a lot.